# Mock module when testing django view

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, mocking

I have a custom function that authenticate a request. I'm trying to mock this module during test but no luck so far

This is my view

```
from auth_utils import authenticate_request, UnauthenticatedRequest

def my_view(request):
    try:
        authenticate_request(request)
    except UnauthenticatedRequest:
        return Http404()
    return render(request, 'ok.html', {'status': 'ok'})
```

And in the test i'm trying to mock `authenticate_request` so it would not raise an error

```
class TestMyView(MyAPITestCase, TestCase):

    @mock.patch('auth_utils.authenticate_request', side_effect=None)
    def setUp(self, mock_auth):
        self.response = self.client.get(reverse('my-view'))

    def test_should_return_ok(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.response.context.get('status'), 'ok')
```

Can't make it work. Any suggestions ?

Thanks, Python 2.7, Django 1.8.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to mock the function `authenticate_request` where it's imported, not where it's defined.

So, for example, if `my_view` is defined in `myapp/views.py`, then `authenticate_request` is imported into `myapp.views`. So you want to call something like the following:

```
@mock.patch('myapp.views.authenticate_request', side_effect=None)
```

Comment: Makes sense ... Thanks.

Comment: No problem. Would recommend you possibly change the title to "mock a function [imported from another module] when testing Django view" as that's technically what you're doing here.